# I am working on a program that checks the spelling of a txt file using a given dictionary in java. I am not getting the right outputs

Tags: java, recursion, spell-checking, binary-search

I am having issues with this program. I cannot get it to read more than the first line of code in the dictionary file. The dictionary file has around 22000 words. If someone could figure this out that would be great. I then could move along with the rest of my code.

```
public class Program2 {

private String[] array;
private String[] array2;


public void readFile(){
    File f = new File ("dictionary.txt"); 
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (f); 
        int i = 0; 
        array = new String [10]; 
        while (i<array.length && input.hasNext()){
            String word = input.nextLine();
            String[] wordarray = word.split(" "); 
            array[i] = wordarray[i];
            i++;
            for (i = 0 ; i<array.length; i++)
                System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
        input.close(); 
    }//try
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}   


public void readFile2(){
    File f = new File ("oliver.txt"); 
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (f); 
        int i = 0; 
        array = new String [10]; 
        while (i<array.length && input.hasNext()){
            String book = input.nextLine();
            String[] bookarray = book.split(" "); 
            array2[i] = bookarray[i];
            i++;
            for (i = 0 ; i<array2.length; i++)
                System.out.println(array2[i]);
        }
        input.close(); 
    }//try
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}   


public int binarysearchrecursive(double key, int first, int last) {
    int mid;
    if (first > last) {
        return -1;
    }
    mid = (first + last) / 2;

    if (key == wordArray[mid]) {
        return mid;
    } else if (key < wordArray[mid]) {
        return binarysearchrecursive(key, first, mid - 1);
    } else {
        return binarysearchrecursive(key, mid + 1, last);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: The bug is your while loops.

Comment: A good start would be to include a small sample input, what your expected output is and what your actual output is.

Comment: @PaulHicks Could you explain where??

Comment: What have you tried? Do not throw the code to us and expect to debug it for you. Did you try to run the program in debug mode and step thru the code? You could use any IDE such as eclipse for this.

Comment: Yes.  Here: `input.nextLine();`.  And here: `String word = input.nextLine();`.  And here: `array[i] = wordarray[i];`.  And here: `i++;`.  And here: `for (i = 0 ; i<array.length; i++)`.  Perhaps you should consider a few tutorials.

Comment: @R0manarmy I have a file with a b c d e f g h i j k on separate lines. This is just for test purposes. I get A and then null null null...

Comment: @PaulHicks I have tried that. That is why I am here.

Comment: Try [rubber ducky debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).  This is not a debugstore.  The bugs are very, very obvious.  It will not help you if we fix your code.  You can fix it quite quickly yourself.

Comment: @PaulHicks What may be obvious to you may not be to everyone else. I am only on my first java lesson.

Comment: May I direct you to [ask] , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as someone commented, I think the problem is in the loops :P

This is what we want to do when we read all the words:

1. Create an ArrayList (better than Array, because you don't know exactly how many words you have in the text file).
2. Then create a double loop (1 while + 1 for) which goes through the file and stores strings in that ArrayList
3. The loops will go through all the lines, and then add every word in the line to the ArrayList (using the split on " " like you are trying).

So:

```
public ArrayList<String> readFile(){
    File f = new File ("dictionary.txt"); 
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (f);
        while (input.hasNext()){
                //Goes through all lines
            String line = input.nextLine();
                //Array of all words:
            String[] wordArray = line.split(" "); 
                //Goes through all words:
            for(String str : wordArray){
                array.add(str);
            }

        }
        input.close(); 
    }//try
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
  return array;
}
```